# elastic search spark stuck on union of two dataframes

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-hadoop, elasticsearch-spark

i am using pyspark to query elastic search
i have the folowing code

```
d1 = data_frame1.collect() # return 1 row
d2 = data_frame2.collect() # return no rows
```

but when i call

```
d3 data_frame1.union(data_frame2).collect()
```

the code is stuck

the collection i am quering has 20 rows
the schema of data_frame1 and data_frame2 is the same

when i call collect on each it returns correct result
but when i merge them and call collect it stuck

i am using elasticsearch-spark-30_2.12-8.9.0
Elasticsearch 8.9.2

the query im am using on both data frames is:

`{ "bool": { "must": [{"term": {"field1": "x1213"}}] }`

I have tried calling count
call on empty db

please help me

call on empty db
change fields

Comment: please help.... its very importatnt